# How to associate a static block with attribute values?

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, cms-block, magento-community

I want to create an `multiselect` attribute with 3 values. When I select the values during product creation It should display the content from the static blocks. So I entered  the `identifier` of the static block under `default store view` (which is `English` below) option during attribute creation like:

[image]

Now in `view.phtml`, I have added the below code:

```
<?php
getResource()->getAttribute('r_n')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockID($cmsstatic)->tohtml();
?>
```

where `r_n` is the `attribute code`.

But am getting error like:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function getResource()
```

Kindly someone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**For select attribute**

```
<?php $attributeValue = $_product->getAttributeText('r_n');?>
<?php if($attributeValue):?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockID($attributeValue)->tohtml(); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

**For multiselect attribute**

```
<?php $attributeValues = $_product->getAttributeText('r_n');?>
<?php if(is_array($attributeValues) & !empty($attributeValues)):?>
<?php foreach($attributeValues as $attributeValue):?>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockID($attributeValue)->tohtml(); ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php elseif($attributeValues):?>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockID($attributeValues)->tohtml(); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: I used your multiselect attribute  code & i get error like "Call to undefined function getAttributeText()"

Comment: hey your code has very small syntax error: $_product>getAttributeText('r_n')
The arrow is not proper. It should be like : $_product->getAttributeText('r_n')
Now its perfectlyy working. Thank you.

Comment: @Ramya U r right and updated ans pls check now

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the option label of an attribute value of the current product in `catalog/product/view.phtml` you can also use:

```
$_product->getAttributeText('r_n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Before getResource() you need to use object of class in which this function has been created.

For example if you are trying to get value of a product attribute, then it should be:

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($product)
```

Comment: Can you explain briefly?

Comment: Please check my modified answer.